# Delegate.BeginInvoke Delay

Tags: c#, multithreading, begininvoke

Sometimes when Delegate.BeginInvoke is invoked, it takes more than one second to execute the delegate method.

What could be the reasons for the delay? I get this issue 1 or 2 times a day in an application which runs continuosly.

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Delegate.BeginInvoke`?

Comment: It is making a new thread - but I don't know how long this should take. Probably very fast.

Comment: Creating a new thread is relatively expensive.

Comment: How are you measuring this delay?  Have you tried doing something like `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);` right before calling `.BeginInvoke()` as well as immediately within the delegate method?

Comment: It is Delegate.BeginInvoke. I measure the difference by logging. There is a log entry before calling BeginInvoke. A log entry is there in the Delegate method also..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thread pool manager makes sure that only as many threads are allowed to execute as you have CPU cores.  As soon as one completes, another one that's waiting in the queue is allowed to execute.

Twice a second, it re-evaluates what's going on with the running threads.  If they don't complete, it assumes they are blocked and allows another waiting thread to run.  On the typical two-core CPU, you'll get two threads running right away, the 3rd thread starts after one second, the 4th thread after 1.5 second, etcetera.

Well, there's your second.  The Q&D fix is to use ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(), but that's the sledgehammer solution.  The real issue is that your program is using thread pool threads for long-running tasks.  Either because they execute a lot of code or because they block on some kind of I/O request.  The latter being the more common case.

The way to solve it is to *not* use a thread pool thread for such a blocking thread but use the Thread class instead.  Don't do this if the threads are actually burning CPU cycles, you'll slow everything down.  Easy to tell, you'll see 100% cpu load in Taskmgr.exe

Comment: Hi Hans,

Thanks for the reply.

Is there any easy way to understand which thread pool thread is blocking on IO or taking more CPU cycles.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know then you use too many of them.  You can find out by logging start+end.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using `Delegate.BeginInvoke` then you're, indirectly, using the `ThreadPool`.  The `ThreadPool` recycles completed threads and allows them to be reused without going through the expense of constructing new threads and tearing completed threads down.

So... when you use `Delegate.BeginInvoke` you're adding the method to be invoked to a queue, as soon as the `ThreadPool` thinks it has an available thread for your task it will execute.  However, if the `ThreadPool` is out of available threads then you'll be left waiting.

`System.Threading.ThreadPool` has several properties and methods to show how many threads are available, maximums, etc.  I would try monitoring those counts to see if it looks like the `ThreadPool` is being spread thin.

*If* that's the case then the best resolution is to ensure that the `ThreadPool` is only being used for short-lived (small) tasks.  If it's being used for long-running tasks then those tasks should be modified to use their own dedicated thread rather than occupying the ThreadPool.

Comment: Hi STW,

How do you monitor ThreadPool parameters? Poll or Something else?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a simple timer, such as `System.Threading.Timer` to invoke a method which could collect and report on the threadpool status

Comment: ...I wasn't aware of this, but it also looks like there may be performance counters available specifically to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650682.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you set the priority of the BeginInvoke?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx

Do you have other BeginInvoke calls waiting?

"If multiple BeginInvoke calls are made at the same DispatcherPriority, they will be executed in the order the calls were made."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx

Comment: It is Delegate.BeginInvoke. I measure the difference by logging. There is a log entry before calling BeginInvoke. A log entry is there in the Delegate method also..